# MySql with Entity Framework 6: Binary(18) to byte[] conversion fails for Subtable

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I have a table **Users** with various column and another table **UserJob**.

**Users table structure:**

```
public byte[] Id { get; set; }
public string language{ get; set; }
public string Password{ get; set; }
```

**UserJob table structure**

```
public byte[] UId { get; set; }
public string MyJob{ get; set; }
```

Now UId in UserJob  table is foreign key for User table.

All the mapping are correctly done via Code first from database technique but when i fetch **DBSet** from Db i only get parent table and get a exception for UserJob table as **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Now Uid in Db is has Datatype **Binary(18)**.

SomeHow conversion from Binary(18) to byte[] fails for subtable but works well for parent table. (In this case ID of User table is also saved as Binary(18) and gets populated pretty well as byte[18] in the output).

So i guess this problem is for Subtable only.

Exception is in MySql.Data dll.

```
 at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBinary.EscapeByteArray(Byte[] bytes, Int32 length, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBinary.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql, MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Asked in mysql forums also, but no answer.  https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,651946,651946
MySql Connector: 6.10.7

**If not solution, any suggestion to go near the problem is also welcomed.**

Comment: Do you have one column of type `BINARY(16)` and one of `BINARY(18)`, or are they both the same size?

Comment: Both the columns are Binary(18). What i don't get it easily map this field in case of parent table but with sub table it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug in MySql.Data. For example, this code crashes with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
using (var command = new MySqlCommand("select @param", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", new byte[16]).Size = 18;
    command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

It seems likely that somewhere in the MySql.Data library, the `MySqlParameter.Size` property is being set to a value larger than the length of the parameter value.

If you can't figure out a workaround, the next best thing to do would be file a bug report (with a concise sample to reproduce the problem) at https://bugs.mysql.com/.

Comment: This certainly a issue in MySql.Data dll, I get the code from Git for MySQl.Data and debug the code where its breaking. it breaks in WriteValue() function in MySql.Data.Types.MySqlBinary Class. Its bringing the length as 128 instead of 18 for a parameter and thus throwing exception.  I'll write a concise sample and report the problem at https://bugs.mysql.com/. as suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this issue is to set maxlength for your parameter.
SomeHow MySql.Data.dll always take parameter length as 128(This is max length) instead of actual parameter length in above case.

So if you set  [MaxLength(18)] for your parameter (Or whatever is your parameter maxlength is in the database), it won't break when it try to map your parameter in MySQl.Data.dll.

Hope this helps someone.